# Removing empty sublists from a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested, sublist

I have the following nested list:

```py
mynestedlist = [[[], [], [], ['Foo'], [], []], [[], ['Bar'], [], []], ['FOO'], 'BAR']
```

I want to flatten it to the outermost items, which would give me 4 items inside the main list. However, I only want the items with text and want to remove the empty bracket lists.

Desired output:

```py
mynestedlist = [[['Bar']], ['FOO'], 'BAR']
```

I have tried the following:

```py
newlist = []
for i in mynestedlist:
    for sub in i:
        if sub != []:
            newlist.append(sub)
```

However, I'm getting the following output:

```py
[['Foo'], ['bar'], 'FOO', 'B', 'A', 'R']
```

Comment: just add another conditional `isinstance(v, list)` to make sure you are only working with lists not characters

Comment: What should happen to `[[[], [], [], [], [], []], [[], ['Bar'], [], []], ['FOO'], 'BAR']`? That has a list that only contains *more* empty lists. Removing just the leaf-node lists (those that are empty *now*) produces `[[], [['Bar']], ['FOO'], 'BAR']` so an empty list at the start. Should this *keep removing empty lists* and produce `[[['Bar']], ['FOO'], 'BAR']`?

Comment: If the latter, what should then happen to `mynestedlist` if you started with `[[[], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], []], []]`? That's a nested structure of empty lists, would you want to end up with `[]`, or is `None` better in that case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a mix of lists and strings, both of which are iterables. You need to explicitly test for lists here, and either recurse or use a stack:

```
def clean_nested(l):
    cleaned = []
    for v in l:
        if isinstance(v, list):
            v = clean_nested(v)
            if not v:
                continue
        cleaned.append(v)
    return cleaned
```

Demo:

```
>>> mynestedlist = [[[], [], [], ['Foo'], [], []], [[], ['Bar'], [], []], ['FOO'], 'BAR']
>>> clean_nested(mynestedlist)
[[['Foo']], [['Bar']], ['FOO'], 'BAR']
```

Note that this solution *removes all but the outermost list* if there are empty lists inside empty lists:

```
>>> nested_empty = [[[],[],[],[],[],[]],[[],['Bar'],[], []], ['FOO'], 'BAR']
>>> clean_nested(nested_empty)
[[['Bar']], ['FOO'], 'BAR']
>>> all_nested_empty = [[[],[],[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[], []], []]
>>> clean_nested(all_nested_empty)
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will do:

```
def del_empty(lst):
    if isinstance(lst, list):
        return [del_empty(sub) for sub in lst if sub != []]
    return lst

>>> del_empty(mynestedlist)
[[['Foo']], [['Bar']], ['FOO'], 'BAR']
```

Comment: This would leave empty lists in place if those lists contain other empty lists: `[[[],[],[],[],[],[]],[[],['Bar'],[], []], ['FOO'], 'BAR']` produces `[[], [['Bar']], ['FOO'], 'BAR']`.

Comment: The question remains if that is desired or not. After all, such lists were not empty to begin with. And what to return if the outer most list is such a list (itself containing only empty lists), that would remain empty, too, also in your solution.

Comment: Fair point. The outermost list is indeed going to be an empty list if there is nothing left.

Answer (score 0):

With some recursion it is possible to remove empty lists at any depth while preserving string elements.

```py
def remove_nested_null(a):
    if not isinstance(a, list):
        return a

    a = map(remove_nested_null, a)
    a = list(filter(None, a))

    return a
```

Comment: Why the nested function? You could remove the `def _recurse(_a):` line, unindent the rest, and just use `a` and `remove_nested_null()` throughout to get the same result.

Comment: Python tips: `len(x) != 0` can be reduced to `x`, an empty list is false-y in a boolean test. You could just use `filter(None, _a)` because that would do the same test (only pick truthy elements).

Comment: You don't need to test for `isinstance(element, list)` *and* `isinstance(_a, list)`; you never recurse when either location tests false. The same goes for your `filter()` test and then `if not element:` test. You can drop the `filter()` loop entirely, because you already make that test *in the loop*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for the tips~ I updated the function with simplified logic

Comment: There is no need to turn the `map()` iterator into a list if you are going to pass it directly to `filter()`. Save yourself a list object creation and destruction cycle there.

Comment: And if you used `filter(None, a)` you avoid the (costly) lambda identity function.

Comment: Finally, personally I find a list comprehension to be more readable: `[v for v in remove_nested_null(a) if v]`. All of which makes your answer ever closer to what 
schwobaseggl wrote.

Comment: Ah, well I personally prefer map/filter to list comprehensions. So, I'll leave it as is :)